# Стакаются inline кнопки aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, inline

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    photo = open('photo_2023-10-07_15-02-11.jpg', 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
    await message.answer("""Салют!
Вас приветствует Бот от компании «SOLO.». Мы создадим для вас вашу персональную вещь с уникальным дизайном по вашему желанию, а так же по доступным ценам .
Мы работаем только с качественными материалами ✅. Наша одежда состоит из % хлопка.""")
    await message.answer("Как я могу к вам обращаться?☺️")
    await Form.number.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.number)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Можете написать свой номер телефона ☎️?")
    await Form.choice.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.choice)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number'] = message.text
        data['msg'] = await message.answer(f"""На какую вещь вы бы хотели нанести свой уникальный принт? (Худи/футболка)
Цены 
Футболка - 15990₸
Худи - 25990₸
Что вы желаете выбрать? """,reply_markup=cloth_kb)
    await Form.size.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Футболка', state=Form.size)
async def process_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['choice'] = "Футболка"
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        size_kb.add(button_xs, button_s, button_M, button_L, button_XL, button_XXL)
        await data['msg'].edit_text("""Какой размер вы желаете выбрать?""", reply_markup=size_kb)
        with open('tshirt.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
            data['photo_msg'] = await bot.send_photo(callback_query.message.chat.id, photo)
        await Form.color.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Худи', state=Form.size)
async def process_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['choice'] = "Худи"
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        size_kb.add(button_xs, button_s, button_M, button_L, button_XL, button_XXL)
        await data['msg'].edit_text("""Какой размер вы желаете выбрать?""", reply_markup=size_kb)
        with open('hoodie.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
            data['photo_msg'] = await bot.send_photo(callback_query.message.chat.id, photo)
        await Form.color.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in {'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'}, state=Form.color)
async def process_size_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['size'] = callback_query.data
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        if data["choice"] == "Футболка":
            await data['msg'].edit_text(f"Вы выбрали размер: {data['size']}\nМожете выбрать цвет вашей будущей футболки ", reply_markup=color_kb)
            await Form.check.set()
        else:
            await data['msg'].edit_text(f"Вы выбрали размер: {data['size']}\nМожете выбрать цвет вашей будущей худи ", reply_markup=color_kb)
            await Form.check.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in {'Белый', 'Черный'}, state=Form.check)
async def process_size_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['color'] = callback_query.data
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        await data['msg'].edit_text(f"""Супер! Давайте проверим верные ли ваши данные? :
Имя - {data['name']}
Номер - {data['number']}
Футболка/Худи - {data['choice']}
Размер - {data['size']}
Цвет - {data['color']}""",reply_markup=yesno_kb)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
происходит такое.
Не знаю в чем проблема.

Comment: Тебе нужно что-бы кнопка Нет была под Да?

Comment: Не. Когда нажимаю нет то идет заполнение данных заново и как видите почему то кнопки стакаюься

Comment: Не понимаю, что означает - стакаються кнопки. Если тебе нужно каждую кнопку с новой "строки", тогда нужно использовать size_kb.row(), если нужно, что-бы все были в одном ряду, тогда в экземпляре класса InlineKeyboardMarkup нужно указать параметр row_width, он определяет максимум кнопок будет в одном ряду

Comment: Все я понял в чем была проблема

Answer (score 0):

```
size_tshirt_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
size_tshirt_kb.add(button_xs,button_s, button_M, button_L, button_XL, button_XXL)
size_hoodie_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
size_hoodie_kb.add(button_s, button_M, button_L, button_XL, button_XXL)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    photo = open('photo_2023-10-07_15-02-11.jpg', 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
    await message.answer("""Салют!
Вас приветствует Бот от компании «SOLO.». Мы создадим для вас вашу персональную вещь с уникальным дизайном по вашему желанию, а так же по доступным ценам .
Мы работаем только с качественными материалами ✅. Наша одежда состоит из % хлопка.""")
    await message.answer("Как я могу к вам обращаться?☺️")
    await Form.number.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.number)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Можете написать свой номер телефона ☎️?")
    await Form.choice.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.choice)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['number'] = message.text
        data['msg'] = await message.answer(f"""На какую вещь вы бы хотели нанести свой уникальный принт? (Худи/футболка)
Цены 
Футболка - 15990₸
Худи - 25990₸
Что вы желаете выбрать? """,reply_markup=cloth_kb)
    await Form.size.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Футболка', state=Form.size)
async def process_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['choice'] = "Футболка"
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        #size_kb.add(button_xs, button_s, button_M, button_L, button_XL, button_XXL)
        await data['msg'].edit_text("""Какой размер вы желаете выбрать?""", reply_markup=size_kb)
        with open('tshirt.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
            data['photo_msg'] = await bot.send_photo(callback_query.message.chat.id, photo)
        await Form.color.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Худи', state=Form.size)
async def process_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['choice'] = "Худи"
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        #size_kb.add(button_xs, button_s, button_M, button_L, button_XL, button_XXL)
        await data['msg'].edit_text("""Какой размер вы желаете выбрать?""", reply_markup=size_kb)
        with open('hoodie.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
            data['photo_msg'] = await bot.send_photo(callback_query.message.chat.id, photo)
        await Form.color.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in {'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'}, state=Form.color)
async def process_size_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['size'] = callback_query.data
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        if data["choice"] == "Футболка":
            await data['msg'].edit_text(f"Вы выбрали размер: {data['size']}\nМожете выбрать цвет вашей будущей футболки ", reply_markup=color_kb)
            await Form.check.set()
        else:
            await data['msg'].edit_text(f"Вы выбрали размер: {data['size']}\nМожете выбрать цвет вашей будущей худи ", reply_markup=color_kb)
            await Form.check.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in {'Белый', 'Черный'}, state=Form.check)
async def process_size_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['color'] = callback_query.data
        data['msg'] = await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback_query.message.chat.id, callback_query.message.message_id)
        await data['msg'].edit_text(f"""Супер! Давайте проверим верные ли ваши данные? :
Имя - {data['name']}
Номер - {data['number']}
Футболка/Худи - {data['choice']}
Размер - {data['size']}
Цвет - {data['color']}""",reply_markup=yesno_kb)
```

Проблема была в том что я каждый раз заново добавлял кнопки в клавиатуру.